# PG restore no space left on device, only restore from where restore failed

Tags: postgresql, diskspace, pg-restore

I ran a `pg_restore` on a large database, but nearing the end of the restore the system ran out of memory:

```
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "user_styles": ERROR:  could not extend file "base/11521287/99526805": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

Is there a way to continue the restore from the point where the memory ran out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will have to drop the partially restored database and start again after increasing the disk space.